# TABLE_PER_CLASS Inheritance not working with secondary tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

I have a Class B that extends Class A with a TABLE_PER_CLASS Inheritance structure. In addition to that, Class A is using a secondary table.

However, when the final SQL is being generated, the secondary table is being ignored. When I remove the inheritance, the secondary table works properly. Is there anyway to make them work together?

The only issue I could find online that was similar to mine was this bug report submitted on the Hibernate website 7 years ago (https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4832), though it seems it was never fixed.

Is this situation just a bug, or is there an extra step that is needed to take place to make it work?

EDIT: Some code examples

Class A:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Table(name = "ClassA")
@SecondaryTable(name = "ClassAView", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id"))
public class ClassA {...
```

Class B:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ClassB")
public class ClassB extends ClassA {...
```

Result:

```
[SQL for all of Inheritance is here, SQL for secondary table doesn't exist]
```

Comment: It looks like that was one of very large number that they just marked as CLOSED (with no fix) because they had a large number of bugs in Hibernate, inadequate resource to look at them all, and maybe an amount of time had passed since it was reported. If it still happens then re-raise it with a testcase

Comment: Used to have a project to map TABLE_PER_CLASS with the parent class and sub classes. It worked with Springboot 4.4, Spring-data-jpa 1.10.x and Hibernate 5. Have you tried with any codes?! Can you post them here?!

Comment: @KennyTaiHuynh TABLE_PER_CLASS works as intended, the problem lies in that the extra Secondary Table for Class A doesn't function unless the Inheritance is removed.